# Checking keys in a defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this code that should run through the keys in the python `defaultdict`, and if the key isn't in the `defaultdict`, it gets added.

I'm getting an error that I don't encounter with regular defined dictionaries, and I'm having a bit of trouble working it out:

The code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def counts(line):
    for word in line.split():
        if word not in defaultdict.keys():
            word = "".join(c for c in word if c not in ('!', '.', ':', ','))
            defaultdict[word] = 0
        if word != "--":
            defaultdict[word] += 1
```

The error:

```
if word not in defaultdict.keys():
TypeError: descriptor 'keys' of 'dict' object needs an argument
```

Comment: `defaultdict` is a class here, not a `defaultdict` *instance*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh I see, thank you.  What is the syntax to create a defaultdict instance in python?

Comment: Besides you can check for an instance key with just `if word in some_dict:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defaultdict` is a class; you need an object:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def counts(line, my_dict):
    for word in line.split():
        if word not in my_dict.keys():
            word = "".join(c for c in word if c not in ('!', '.', ':', ','))
            my_dict[word] = 0 
        if word != "--":
            my_dict[word] += 1


my_dict = defaultdict()

counts("Now is the time for all good parties to come to the aid of man.", my_dict)
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(None, {'Now': 1, 'is': 1, 'the': 2, 'time': 1, 'for': 1, 'all': 1, 'good': 1, 'parties': 1, 'to': 2, 'come': 1, 'aid': 1, 'of': 1, 'man': 1})
```

Answer (score 5):

You did not construct a `defaultdict` *object* here, you simply refer to the `defaultdict` class.

You can create one, like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def counts(line):
    dd = defaultdict(int)
    for word in line.split():
        word = ''.join(c for c in word if c not in ('!', '.', ':', ','))
        if word not in dd:
            dd[word] = 0
        if word != '--':
            dd[word] += 1
    return dd
```

That being said, you probably want to use a `Counter` here, like:

```
from collections import Counter

def counts(line):
    words = (
        ''.join(c for c in word if c not in ('!', '.', ':', ',')) for word in line.split()
    )
    return Counter(
        word for word in words if word != '--'
    )
```